# Auto indexing not working

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am having some trouble getting my auto indexing to work.

While the neo4j service was stopped I changed the neo4j.properties file and set: `#node_auto_indexing=true`

Then typed my indexing keys like so: `#node_keys_indexable=Name,Type,GUID,CurrentVersion,DateTimeCreated,CurrentVersionDateTimeCreated,VersionCount,CustomerName,DocumentReferece,Version`.

I then started the service again and did the following: 
`neo4j-sh (0)$ index --create node_auto_index -t Node`

I then created some nodes and ran the following query:

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ start n = node:node_auto_index(Name = "Quote") return n;
```

The results were:

```
==> +---+
==> | n |
==> +---+
==> +---+
==> 0 row
==> 237 ms
```

I am using neo4j-advanced-2.0.0-M02 with the Neo4jClient for .NET and C#.
Is there anything that I am doing wrong here or are there perhaps any other configuration steps that I am missing.

I have tried the following:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358797/working-with-index-in-neo4j%22Number%201%22), [2](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/neo4j/132p0wa94j/auto-indexing-never-works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really have `#` in front of your config file lines still?--because if so, they're commented out. You shouldn't need to manually create an autoindex.

Comment: i sure sound like a noob now!

Comment: happens to the best of us ;)